# PHP Injection not displaying echo in textbox

Tags: php, html

I was trying to insert some `php code` into one of those dummy practice sites but it isn't displaying anything on the page after submitting the field.

So in the name field, I typed in `<?php echo "test"; ?>`. So after I submit this, I expect to see something like `Name: test` but instead I am seeing `Name:`. So like nothing is showing after the name. So when I inspect the element on my web browser, I see this `<p> Name: </p><pre><?php echo "test"; ?></pre>`

Is the `php` code not running?

Comment: what is the file extenion of your file? `.php`?

Comment: filename is index.php

Comment: Update your question to specify which one of the _"dummy practice sites"_ you were using.

Answer (score -1):

> Is the php code not running?

No, it isn't. The code is just being output back to the browser (where it is treated as an unknown HTML tag).

This is probably because the "dummy practise site" is not set up to allow people to execute arbitrary PHP on their servers simply by submitting it over HTTP, which would be a massive security problem and rapidly turn them into either:

- A bitcoin farm
- A spam farm
- Both

Answer (score -1):

It Will not work.
PHP is a server side . You can't run PHP on client side.